# Vb.net Gridview template field checkbox selected should get row values

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_auth" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped w-100 table_permission">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="auth_id" HeaderText="PRIVILEGE ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="auth_dpt" HeaderText="DEPARTMENT" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="auth_desc" HeaderText="PRIVILEGES" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <label class='switch'>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkrow" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Auth_Selected") %>' /><span class='slider'></span>
                            </label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

When ever i click on checkbox 'chkrow' in template field i should have to get respective row values such as auth_id,auth_dpt,auth_desc etc `enter code here`

Comment: What does "get" mean?

Comment: When ever i check or uncheck on checkbox in template field i need to get the row index or the row values, I can not use the <asp:checkboxfield> instead of template field because i am using some design over there in the template field